# How to rasterize a shapefile in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, rasterization

I have several shapefiels that i have to turn into raster.
    Here's the coastline

```
coastline<-readShapeSpatial("shp")
r <- raster(ncols=90, nrows=45)
jd<-rasterize(coastline,r)
plot(jd)
```

it  gives an empty thing with no map, a blank thing.

Comment: that question is not answered apparently and also downvoted.This is another effort more precise.Hope finds thorough answer this time

Comment: It's answered now ... if you're not getting a response, the practice on this site is to edit your question, sharing more about aims and where you're getting stuck, to make sure you're going to get a good response.

Comment: Sorry @Simbamangu, noticed too late you already answered the related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider to tell us why the above code didn't work, i.e. include the referring error message. I just tried to reproduce your issue using the German border from the `countriesCoarse` dataset included in the **rworldmap** package and everything worked out fine. Remember to set the projection and the desired extent of your raster template properly, otherwise it will range from `-180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)`, which would be way too much for our purposes.

```
## german borders
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)
library(raster)

data(countriesCoarse)
spy_germany <- subset(countriesCoarse, GEOUNIT == "Germany")
sln_germany <- as(spy_germany, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")

## raster template
rst_template <- raster(ncols = 30, nrows = 60, 
                       crs = projection(sln_germany), 
                       ext = extent(sln_germany))

## rasterize
rst_germany <- rasterize(sln_germany, rst_template)
plot(rst_germany, col = "grey75", legend = FALSE, xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
plot(rasterToPolygons(rst_germany), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how extent works  and what refers to?

Comment: `extent` extracts the northern, eastern, southern and western bounding coordinate from 'sln_germany' and assigns those geographic limits to the raster template via the 'ext' parameter. Have a look at `?raster::extent` for further information.