# Why does the function rasterize change my coordinates?

Tags: r, rasterization

I need to import a shapefile into R and turn it into a Raster object. I am using the following code:

```
map <- readOGR("path and file name")
r <- raster(ncol=4001, nrow=4001)
r <- rasterize(map, r)
```

When I import the shapefile, the resulting SpatialPolygonsDataFrame has the correct coordinates and extent:

> map
> class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
> features    : 1
> extent      : 22.97518, 23.09783, -34.09091, -34.0243  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
> variables   : 11
> names       :       Name, descriptio, timestamp, begin, end, altitudeMo, tessellate, extrude, visibility, drawOrder, icon
> value       : Knysna box,         NA,        NA,    NA,  NA,         NA,         -1,       0,         -1,        NA,   NA

However, as soon as I try to rasterize the object, it completely changes the coordinates and extent:

> r
> class      : RasterLayer
> dimensions : 4001, 4001, 16008001  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
> resolution : 0.08997751, 0.04498875  (x, y)
> extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
> crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
> source     : memory
> names      : layer
> values     : 1, 1  (min, max)
> attributes :
> ID       Name descriptio timestamp begin  end altitudeMo tessellate extrude visibility drawOrder
> 1 Knysna box                                -1       0         -1      
> icon

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can specify the coordinate system with afterwards  crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"  as shown here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111226/how-to-assign-crs-to-rasterlayer-in-r

Comment: Thanks for your quick response - the crs is already set to WGS84, and even if I run your code, it still has the same changed coordinates and extent:
> crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> r
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 4001, 4001, 16008001  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.08997751, 0.04498875  (x, y)
extent     : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory

Comment: maybe try and check out this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154195/how-to-rasterize-a-shapefile-in-r

Comment: Ok setting the extent manually when rasterizing seems to have done the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Your welcome! :)

Comment: maybe you can accept the answer I added below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code for converting a shapefile into a raster

```
## german borders
library(rgdal)
library(rworldmap)
library(raster)

data(countriesCoarse)
spy_germany <- subset(countriesCoarse, GEOUNIT == "Germany")
sln_germany <- as(spy_germany, "SpatialLinesDataFrame")

## raster template
rst_template <- raster(ncols = 30, nrows = 60, 
                       crs = projection(sln_germany), 
                       ext = extent(sln_germany))

## rasterize
rst_germany <- rasterize(sln_germany, rst_template)
plot(rst_germany, col = "grey75", legend = FALSE, xlab = "lon", ylab = "lat")
plot(rasterToPolygons(rst_germany), add = TRUE)
```

as @fdetsch answered in this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154195/how-to-rasterize-a-shapefile-in-r)